# Make ctype char/char arrays and derived char/char arrays act similarly

Tags: python, python-2.7, ctypes

I am updating ctype structures that contain `ctypes.c_char` and `ctypes.c_char` array fields to now use derived types. In order to make things easier on users, I would like to make ctype Structures that contain these `c_char` fields act like other ctype arrays. For example, when accessing a `ctypes.c_ubyte * 5` array, the user still has access to the ctype array, but when accessing a `ctypes.c_char * 5` array you only ever obtain a Python string.

Here's some example structures I have:

```
import ctypes
class chr(ctypes.c_char):
    pass

class str(ctypes.Array):
    _type_ = chr
    _length_ = 5

class old_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('str', ctypes.c_char * 5), ('char', ctypes.c_char)]

class new_struct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('str', str), ('char', chr)]
```

When accessing these fields I get:

```
old = old_struct()
print old.str         # ''
print old.char        # '\x00'

new = new_struct()
print new.str         # ''
print new.char        # <chr object at ...>
print new.char.value  # '\x00'
```

How would I go about making the `new.str` act like it is now, but also contain a `value` datamember that when accessed returns the contained Python string. I would also like a deprecation warning to appear if a user accesses `new.str` without specifying `value` (i.e. `new.str.value`).
I would also like `new.char` to act like `old.char` for backwards compatibility, but also keep its current functionality. I would like a deprecation warning to appear if a user accesses `new.char` without specifying `value` (i.e. `new.char.value`).

Comment: Field descriptors for `c_char` and `c_wchar` array types use a `GETFUNC` and `SETFUNC`. This is configured in [`PyCField_FromDesc`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l30) (line 107).

Comment: You'll need to make the field private, e.g. `_str` and then create a `str` property that returns an instance of your array subclass. You can use the array's `from_address` constructor based on the struct address plus the field offset, e.g. `str.from_address(addressof(self) + type(self)._str.offset)`.